# How to combine multiple dynamic columns into a single column on a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine multiple dynamic columns into a single column on a new sheet. I have written code that transfers choices made from multiple drop down menus in which the user can select multiple options into their own cell. I am trying to create a function that transfers these selections into a single column on a new sheet. If anyone could tell me how to transfer this changing range of rows within about 8 columns into a new sheet that would be great, or if it is easier to directly put the selections on the new sheet that would work as well.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Row = 11 Then
  Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
  Set rng = Range("A11:H11")
  For Each cell In rng
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Newvalue = Target.Value
     Application.Undo
     Oldvalue = Target.Value
       If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
        Dim val As String
        val = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = val
       Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & "; " & Newvalue
            'below begins addition from Shanell
            Dim txt As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim FullName As Variant

            txt = ActiveCell.Value

            FullName = Split(txt, ";")

            For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
                ActiveCell.Offset(i, 9).Value = FullName(i)
            Next i
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
  Next cell
End If
Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
lastCell = rng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1
'Attempt to copy to new sheet'
For iCol = 11 To rng.Columns.Count
    Range(Cells(11, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol)).Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Links").Range("lastCell,A3")
    lastCell = lastCell + rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count

Next iCol
```

I have tried this code and there are no errors, but the values do not show up on the new sheet. I have added a comment where I attempt to copy the values to a new sheet.

I also tried a line of code like this:

```
Range("J11", Range("Q11").End(xlDown)).Copy Worksheets("Links").Range("A3:A")
```

However, this did not work either.

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in the Worksheet_Change event?  Can you add an image or something that shows the before state and what you want as the after state?  I'm confused by the specifics of what you're wanting to achieve.  Also, this ... ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Links").Range("lastCell,A3") ... simply won't work.  Look up the usage of the Range object for more help.

Comment: There is insufficient information in your post to reproduce your problem. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question to provide additional information, so we may better help you.

Comment: I have updated my post with most of my code. Since most of it is in a loop I couldn't really make it any smaller. I am thinking that it may be easier to implement a copy line within the loop, but I am now having issues with new selections overwriting values already on the new worksheet.